# Extracting Metadata from Website

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags, metadata

I was wondering if there's a way in javascript that allows me to process the html source code that allows me to take out specific  tags that I want?

Sorry if it sounds easy or too simple. i am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the HTML in a string, then you can use:

```
var str = '<html></html>'; // your html text goes here
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var dom = div.firstChild; // dom is the object you want,
                          // you can manipulate it using standard dom methods
```

Alternately, use jQuery. jQuery is a library to help you manipulate and access HTML elements more easily. First, add this to the head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is a reference to the jQuery library. Then, do:

```
var foo = $("<html>Your html here</html>");
```

Or, if your html is in a variable (e.g. str), you can do:

```
var foo = $(str);
```

Then, you can manipulate and parse foo in a number of ways. For example, to remove all paragraph elements, you would use

```
foo.remove('p');
```

Or, to remove the paragraph element with id="bar", use:

```
foo.remove('p.bar');
```

Once you are done your modifications, you can get the new html text using:

```
foo.html();
```

Why is your html in a string? Is it not the html of the current page?

Comment: If it is the html of the current page, you can simply use the already-built DOM object.

Comment: and then dom.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0].getAttribute("author") for example

Comment: The equivalent of what mplungjan proposes above using jQuery would be (assuming your jQuery variable is foo): foo.filter('meta').attr('author');

Answer (score -1):

Use DOM it can pull data from webpages if you know the structure.

Comment: thanks, but currently i have the whole html source code in a string, is there anyway to process it instead? because the structure may vary, what is constant is the meta property tag.